# Python regular expression replacement doesn't work as I expect

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to replace part of a string. This is an example of the string:

```
string = u'/nl/nl/1681/1/0/a/all/'
pattern = r'(/\w{2}/\w{2}/)(\d+)/(\d+)(/\d+/[ans]/all/)'
pattern_obj = re.compile(pattern)
```

The pattern specifies 4 groups. If you do a search then the results are as follows:

```
m = pattern_obj.search(string)
m.group(0) -> u'/nl/nl/1681/1/0/a/all/'
m.group(1) -> u'/nl/nl/'
m.group(2) -> u'1681'
m.group(2) -> u'1'
m.group(4) -> u'/0/a/all/'
```

So far so good. Now I specify a replacement string as follows:

```
replacement = r'\1' + '1000' + '/' + '20' + r'\4'
```

and issue the following statement:

```
pattern_obj.sub(replacement,string)
```

and this results in:

```
u'H00/20/0/a/all/'
```

I expected this:

```
u'/nl/nl/1000/20/0/a/all/'
```

I must be doing something wrong but I don't know what. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 3):

Your replacement string, when it's fully assembled, is `\11000/20\4` and `\110` gets interpreted as the octal escape for `H` rather than a back-reference to group number 1 followed by `10`.

You need to write `\g<1>` instead of `\1` to make sure that it's unambiguously a back-reference. See [the documentation for `re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub).